Identify <, >, & and replace it with &lt; ,&gt; , &amp; in a given string, where they are appearing individually and not part of a html or ssml tag
Need a Javascript code snippet that can identify <, >, & and replace it with < ,> , & in a given string, where they are appearing individually and not part of a html or ssml tag.
For example-
'This is a <b>bold</b> & <i>italic</i> text. While this < is a non closing bracket like this <3.'

Should be converted to
'This is a <b>bold</b> & <i>italic</i> text. While this &lt; is a non closing bracket like this &lt;3.'

Tried multiple regex logic but one or the other edge case is always failing. Any help would be appreciated.

It looks like you've gotten an invalid HTML document. I'd try to fix the problem at the source instead. Ask the provider of this invalid document to fix it.

Please include the regex you've built so far, so we can help you fix it. Note that any solution here is going to fail on many potential inputs, you really can't tell the difference between an HTML reserved character and a simple less-than sign in arbitrary text. The difference is in intent, it's not encoded in the text.

If this is in a browser environment, I'd suggest using DOMParser to leverage the browser's built-in tolerance of malformed HTML. For example, in my browser, const dirty = 'This is a <b>bold</b> & <i>italic</i> text. While this < is a non closing bracket like this <3.'; followed by const clean = new DOMParser().parseFromString(dirty, 'text/html').body.innerHTML; sets clean to 'This is a <b>bold</b> &amp; <i>italic</i> text. While this &lt; is a non closing bracket like this &lt;3.'.

You could match all tags and replace them with placeholders. After that, you can replace all the HTML entities with tier respective codes. Finally, you can restore the original tags.
I chose a placeholder pattern of {@[n]} where n is an index starting from 0 (controlled by the length of the placeholders array).


const TAG_PATTERN = /<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g;
  
const entityMap = {
  '&' : '&amp;',
  '<' : '&lt;',
  '>' : '&gt;',
  '"' : '&quot;',
  "'" : '&#39;'
};

const append = (arr, item) => (arr.push(item), arr);

const escapeHTMLEntitiesPreserveTags = (str) => {
  const placeholders = [];
  return str
    // Temporarily replace all tags with placeholders
    .replace(TAG_PATTERN, (match) => `{@[${append(placeholders, match).length - 1}]}`)
    // Escape all HTML entities in the modified string
    .replace(/[&<>"']/g, (char) => entityMap[char] ?? char)
    // Restore original tags
    .replace(/\{@\[(\d+)\]\}/g, (_, index) => placeholders[+index]);
};

const inputText = 'This is a <b>bold</b> & <i>italic</i> text.\n' +
                  'While this < is a non closing bracket like this <3.\n' +
                  'Also, 1 > 0 & "quoted" text with single \'quotes\'.';

console.log(escapeHTMLEntitiesPreserveTags(inputText));



Expected Output
This is a <b>bold</b> &amp; <i>italic</i> text.
While this &lt; is a non closing bracket like this &lt;3.
Also, 1 &gt; 0 &amp; &quot;quoted&quot; text with single &#39;quotes&#39;.

